# How can i get committed data from db in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am trying to commit two models one after the other and build relationship between two tables.

first i will commit address table and second img_details table.

after i commit address table i want to get id of that record and then use that id to insert into second table in of the columns. so that, i will create a relationship.

But, i can not find a way to get current session committed row from db.

Please suggest me best approach to achieve it.

my db session code:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow, fields, schema
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:admin@localhost/timesheet'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

ma = Marshmallow(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=False)
    zip_code = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=False)
    img_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('img_details.id'), nullable=False)


class img_details(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(4000), unique=False)
    short_description = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    address_id = db.relationship('address', backref='img_details', lazy='joined')


class imgDataSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = img_details

    id = ma.auto_field()
    img_url = ma.auto_field()
    description = ma.auto_field()
    short_description = ma.auto_field()
    # address_id = ma.auto_field()


class addressDataSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = address

    id = ma.auto_field()
    city = ma.auto_field()
    state = ma.auto_field()
    zip_code = ma.auto_field()
    img_details = ma.Nested(imgDataSchema, attribute='img_details')
    # img_details = ma.Nested(imgDataSchema)


img_data = imgDataSchema(many=True)
address_data = addressDataSchema(many=True)

# enable CORS
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origin': '*'}})


@app.route('/user_data', methods=["POST"])
def user_image():
    description_value = request.form['description']
    short_description_value = request.form['short_description']
    img_url_value = request.form['uploaded_file']
    address_zip_code_value = request.form['address_zip_code']
    address_city_value = request.form['address_city']
    address_state_value = request.form['address_sate']

    upload_img_data = img_details(
        img_url=img_url_value,
        short_description=short_description_value,
        description=description_value,
    )
    db.session.add(upload_img_data)
    db.session.commit()

    upload_address_details = address(
        zip_code=address_zip_code_value,
        city=address_city_value,
        state=address_state_value
    )
    db.session.add(upload_address_details)
    db.session.commit()
    print(db.session.object_session(upload_address_details))
    return jsonify({'result': 'submitted'})


@app.route('/user_data', methods=["GET"])
def get_img_data():
    # all_list = img_details.query.join(address).add_columns(img_details.img_url,
    #                                                        img_details.address_id,
    #                                                        img_details.short_description,
    #                                                        address.id)
    all_list = img_details.query.join(address).all()
    # all_list = img_details.query.all()
    result = img_data.dump(all_list)
    return jsonify({'response': result})


@app.route('/address', methods=["GET"])
def get_address_data():
    all_list = img_details.query.all()
    result = address_data.dump(all_list)
    return jsonify({'response': result})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: can you show your address class and other class

Comment: updating code with whole code i written @python_user

Comment: once you insert `upload_address_details` to `address`, where do you want to create the other relation with? does something like `img_details(other_values_here, address_id=upload_address_details)` not work for you? you don't need the id if you are using the relationship to insert, sqlachemy will find that

Comment: I did not read that properly, you need to do `upload_address_details = address(zip_code=address_zip_code_value, city=address_city_value, state=address_state_value, img_details=[upload_img_data])` or `upload_address_details = address(zip_code=address_zip_code_value, city=address_city_value, state=address_state_value, img_details=upload_img_data)` depending on 1 to 1 relation or 1 to many relation, does that work for you?

Comment: It gave me error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2023 10:31:57] "POST /user_data HTTP/1.1" 500 -" @python_user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253723/discussion-between-venkat-g-and-python-user).

Answer (score 0):

adding "img_details=upload_img_data" to upload_address_details it worked.
overall code for it:

```py
upload_address_details = address(
        zip_code=address_zip_code_value,
        city=address_city_value,
        state=address_state_value,
        img_details=upload_img_data
    )
```

Thanks to @python_user